# Is the inequality $x^4 (\ln (x^4) - 1) \ge x - e$, with $x>0$, true?

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms

The inequality
$$
x^4 (\ln (x^4) - 1) \ge x - e \qquad (x>0)
$$
is giving me some trouble. It is fairly crude, with the straight line in the right member lying well below the graph of the left member. Straightforward differentiation seems unpromising unless I've missed something. Potential proof approaches would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xvvzyqli4c

Comment: I think you have a typo...you mean $x>0$

Comment: @MyGlasses ... thanks for the correction https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hakma2aqzs

Comment: @Peter you did not write the inequality corectly in wolfram

Comment: @MariosGretsas You are right, sorry.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4(log(x%5E4)-1)%3E%3Dx-e

Comment: Is there something wrong with the inequality for $x=0$ ? It holds there in a limiting sense, correct?

Comment: I don't understand the new title. My question wasn't "Does it hold?" as it clearly does (even as $x \to 0$). My question was how it could be proved. Oh well, I guess I need to hang around and learn the rules of the community.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is equivalent to $x(\log x-1)\geq x^{1/4}-e$, and this is a fairly simple inequality to prove, since the LHS is a convex function while the RHS is a concave function on $\mathbb{R}^+$. For instance,
$$ g(x)=x^{1/4}-e \leq g'(1)(x-1)+g(1) = \tfrac{1}{4}(x-1)+(1-e) $$
while by setting $f(x)=x(\log x-1)$ we have $f'(x)=\log x$, from which
$$ f(x) \geq f'(e^{1/4})(x-e^{1/4})+f(e^{1/4}) = \tfrac{1}{4}(x-e^{1/4})-\tfrac{3}{4}e^{1/4} $$
and the claim follows from
$$ e \geq \tfrac{3}{4}+e^{1/4} $$
which is quite crude and rather simple to prove.

Comment: (With your permission I will change "$(e-1)$" to "$(1-e)$" in the first displayed equation.)

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x) = x^4(\ln(x^4)-1)$. Then
$$f'(x) = 4x^3(\ln(x^4)-1)+x^4\left(\frac{4}{x}\right) = 4x^3\ln(x^4) $$
from which we see thar $f'(x)<0$ for $0<x<1$. Since $f(1) = -1>1-e$, it follows that $f(x)>x-e$ for all $0<x<1$ since $f$ is decreasing on $(0,1)$, while $x-e$ is increasing.

In addition, since $f'(x)>0$ for $x>1$, it follows that for $x\in[1,e^{1/4}]$ we have
$$ f(x)\ge f(1) = -1 > e^{1/4}-e \ge x-e,$$
thus showing that $f(x)>x-e$ on $[1,e^{1/4}]$. Finally, for $x>e^{1/4}$ we have
$$ f'(x) = 4x^3\ln(x^4)> 4e^{3/4}\ln((e^{1/4})^4) > 1, $$
and since $f(e^{1/4})> e^{1/4}-e$, it follows that $f(x)>x-e$ on $(e^{1/4},\infty)$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

For $x>0$ we'll prove a stronger inequality:
$$x^4 (\ln x^4 - 1) \ge x - \frac{6154}{2401}$$ or
$f(x)>0$, where
$$f(x)=\ln{x}-\frac{x^4+x-\frac{6154}{2401}}{4x^4}.$$
Indeed,
$$f'(x)=\frac{(7x-8)(1372x^3+1568x^2+1792x+3077)}{9604x^5},$$
which gives $x_{min}=\frac{8}{7}$ and since
$$f\left(\frac{8}{7}\right)=\ln\frac{8}{7}-\frac{343}{8192}>0,$$
we are done!